# How can I append int value to int array in Hive without UDF?

Tags: hive

I have an int column `main_region` and an int array column `regions`.

Is there any way to do something like
`SELECT append(main_region, regions) ...` without UDF?

Answer (score 1):

Hive is very limited in terms of UDFs for array manipulation.

If it was a string array, you could have used `concat_ws` and `split`.

For the general case, I think `explode` and `collect_list` can be used, but it would be **very** inefficient.

Your best bet is to implement a one-line UDF...